# WPF Pass the debugger on to a newly spawned process

Tags: c#, wpf, debugging, attach-to-process

I have an application that spawns a new process.  During development of the application, I would like to attach a debugger to the new process.  Currently I can do that through Visual Studios Attach to Process functionality, but it's a pain to go back and attach it manually every single time when I need to test a minor change to the code.

Is it possible to spawn a new process using Process.Start and then attach any debuggers that are currently attached to the *current* process onto the *new* process?

I.E.:

Start Process1 with debugging enabled
Process1 starts Process2
Process1 attaches the debugger to Process2

Comment: is the new process a C# program, a C++ program, etc?

Comment: new program is a c# program

Comment: @MikeCorcoran - how would you do the same thing if it was a C++ program spawned from a C# program?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Not a very clean solution, but you could do something like this:

- In Process1, if you're running in Debug mode (`Debugger.IsAttached`), pass an argument to Process2 (e.g. `process2.exe /debug`)
- In Process2, if the process is started with the `/debug` argument, attach the debugger from code (`Debugger.Launch()`)

Answer (score 2):

As an FYI to anyone else looking at this, here is the code implementation of Thomas Levesque's (accepted) answer:

Code

Launching app:

```
Process.Start(/** Path to assembly **/, System.Diagnostics.Debugger.IsAttached ? "/Debug" : "");
```

Target app:

```
if (Environment.GetCommandLineArgs().Contains("/Debug"))
    System.Diagnostics.Debugger.Launch();
```

This will cause most instances of Visual Studio to prompt you with this when the new process starts:

[image]

This is normal...just hit 'Yes, debug [assembly name]'.  The next window will prompt you to choose the debugger to attach to, which usually defaults to the debugger that was orignaly used to launch the starting app

Comment: You could simplify the test in the target app: `if (Environment.GetCommandLineArgs().Contains("/Debug"))`

Comment: agreed...I always do database queries with linq to entities so I always wind up falling back to FirstOrDefault checking the primary key property lol, gotta remember that it's not always necessary...